# Room update query with muliple columns

Tags: android-room

A weird behaviour when I update my entity using this query:

```
@Query("UPDATE profile SET firstName=:newProfileFirstName AND lastName=:newProfileLastName WHERE userId = :userId")

fun updateProfileFullName(
    newProfileFirstName: String,
    newProfileLastName: String,
    userId: Long
) : Completale
```

The issue is after update I always get : *firstname* set to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by replacing **AND** by **,**

```
@Query("UPDATE profile SET firstName=:newProfileFirstName AND lastName=:newProfileLastName WHERE userId = :userId")
```

become :

```
@Query("UPDATE profile SET firstName=:newProfileFirstName, lastName=:newProfileLastName WHERE userId = :userId")
```